# Sending data to a view extended by other views in Laravel

Tags: php, view, laravel, extend

I have a main view that is extended by different other views. Main views has a header and left sidebar.

Headers has 3 buttons with bubbles on it: `Stories, New User and, Returning Users.` Bubble on menu display information, like bubble on `New Users` shows count of visitors who signed up today.

This view is extended by all other views used in different controller methods.

This is the main view

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{-- Header--}}
        <ul id="headernav">
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#hoots">Hoots & Stories</a><span>{{$todayHootStories}}</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#nusers">New Users</a><span>{{$newVisitorsToday}}</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#rusers">Returning Users</a><span>{{$retVisitorsToday}}</span></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        {{-- Sidebar --}}
        <nav>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="i_house">
                    <a href="{{route('dashboard')}}">
                        <span> Overview</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="i_user">
                    <a href="{{route('users')}}">
                        <span>Users</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="i_user">
                    <a href="{{route('categories')}}">
                        <span>Categories</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        {{-- Space For Content --}}
        <div id="content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Header needs three variables `$todayHootStories, $newVisitorsToday, $retVisitorsToday`. Now i need to include these variables from each method of different controllers to make it work properly.

Is there any other way around?

Comment: yes - populate those variables in the controllers constructor

Comment: But still i need to send these variables in each controller method whose view is extending this main view.

Comment: No, you can send the data in the contstructor: `View::share('todayHootStories', $todayHootStories);` and now $todayHootStories is available to all views in all methods

Comment: A slightly nicer approach would be to use a view composter: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers EDIT as noted in the answer by Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [View composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

```
View::composer('profile', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

You can find a good tutorial on adding this to your layout [here](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout).